# Where can I read about Valleytronics?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Where can I read about [Valleytronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valleytronics)? Are there any good books or review papers on this topic? And which are the most influential papers?

The question was also posted at the [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11996/671) site.

Comment: What's "valleytronics"? (Yes, I realize that's kind-of the question, but it would be nice if the question at least spent a single sentence explaining to its reader what it's talking about)

Comment: @ACuriousMind i think it has to do with the valleys (at K and K' in graphene for instance) being considered a quantum number. Also, there are some selection rules in the coupling with electromagnetic field. I think you can target electrons from one valley or the other with circulary polarized light for example.

Comment: If you don't find any answers here, consider to ask this on matter modeling SE.

Comment: @TobiasFünke ill give it a try. Thanks :)

Comment: Your question seems to be answered by the Wikipedia article that Qmechanic linked to.

Comment: @Ghoster this link? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valleytronics. Its very brief and its references are more on the experimental side i think. Im interested in the theoretical point of view